# Let angularjs not to add slashes before every single and double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use the following to bind html to a span tag.

```
<span ng-bind-html="qn.quest_text"></span>
```

But the content get displayed with slashes before every single and double quotes.

Example :
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

How can I prevent angular from adding slashes before every quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Add angular sanitize to your application.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might be your backend is returning escaped text.

Comment: In my controller I am getting the original text from database(text without any slashes).Issue occurs while displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strict Contextual Escaping (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to escape your Text.

What you need to do is, include the `$sce` service into your controller, define a small function which turns your text into trusted, for example :

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
}
```

Then you can simply use this in your view, like this,

```
<span ng-bind-html="to_trusted(qn.quest_text)"></span>
```

You can also try, `trustAs(type, value)` method, where you can try different types, e.g. url, resourceUrl, html, js and css.

Hope this helps.